# ReportLab - Can't mask image [Google App Engine]

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf-generation, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I am generating a PDF using ReportLab, on Google App Engine.

I can draw images in the PDF, but I cannot get a mask to be applied.

Here's my code for drawing a simple green-masked circle (and the circle):

```
# Draw a circle mask over the profile image
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('pdf_profile_mask.jpg'))
c.drawImage(path, 62, 62, 126, 126, mask=[0,255,200,255,0,255])
```

[image: green-circle mask image]

It didn't work, so I tried masking ALL colors (I would expect nothing to get drawn):

```
c.drawImage(path, 62, 62, 126, 126, mask=[0,255,0,255,0,255])
```

But that didn't work either - the image was solid.

ReportLab doesn't support images out of the box on AppEngine - but the [changes you make to get it to run](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Generating-PDFs-on-App-Engine-Python-and-introducing-Mapvelopes) are minor and I don't think they should affect this.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Probably a silly question, but have you made sure to clear/delete the figure between attempts?  Maybe you're just plotting over an old version?

Comment: Each server request creates a new PDF -- is that what you mean?

Comment: Yep, exactly what I meant.  Sorry, I haven't worked with ReportLab before, so I don't think I can help beyond my "silly question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't work for me either with a JPG image. Converting it to PNG did the trick.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much, for some reason I thought only JPEGs were supported, but I'd just forgotten to enable PIL in app engine.